# SSH Key Auth failed ... sometimes with SSSD

Tags: sshd, pam, sssd

I have an issue with one of my server

I use keys to authenticate on my server with AD account, it works most of the time.
SSSD module is used to authenticate AD user.

Sometimes i can't authenticate with my AD users, it seems that the server tries with local user

Here it's working authentication

```
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "blueway-prod.XXXXXXXXXX.fr"
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: Postponed gssapi-with-mic for sagex3 from 192.168.60.184 port 49310 ssh2
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method publickey
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 285005224/285000513 (e=0/0)
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: trying public key file /home/XXXXXXXXXX.FR/sagex3/.ssh/authorized_keys
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: fd 8 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: matching key found: file /home/XXXXXXXXXX/sagex3/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: Found matching RSA key: ca:38:16:a0:d0:ca:60:6b:28:63:09:5b:01:b2:90:d1
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: Postponed publickey for sagex3 from 192.168.60.184 port 49310 ssh2
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method publickey
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6762]: debug1: attempt 3 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 285005224/285000513 (e=0/0)
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: trying public key file /home/XXXXXXXXXX/sagex3/.ssh/authorized_keys
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: fd 8 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: matching key found: file /home/XXXXXXXXXX/sagex3/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: Found matching RSA key: ca:38:16:a0:d0:ca:60:6b:28:63:09:5b:01:b2:90:d1
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep 17 15:06:02 x3v6prod sshd[6759]: debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
```

And here not working authentication

```
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1:userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method none
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "sagex3"
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "blueway-prod.XXXXXXXXXX.fr"
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: Postponed gssapi-with-mic for sagex3 from 192.168.60.184 port 49314 ssh2
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method publickey
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 285005224/285000513 (e=0/0)
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: trying public key file /home/SAGEX3/.ssh/authorized_keys
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: KEX done
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/SAGEX3/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 285005224/285000513 (e=0/0)
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: trying public key file /home/SAGEX3/.ssh/authorized_keys2
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/SAGEX3/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: Failed publickey for sagex3 from 192.168.60.184 port 49314 ssh2
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method none
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6799]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method password
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: attempt 3 failures 1
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: Failed none for sagex3 from 192.168.60.184 port 49314 ssh2
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method password
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: attempt 4 failures 2
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6792]: Failed password for sagex3 from 192.168.60.184 port 49314 ssh2
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: userauth-request for user sagex3 service ssh-connection method password
Sep 17 15:06:06 x3v6prod sshd[6795]: debug1: attempt 5
```

And SSSD logs

```
Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): GPO-based access control failed.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): Ignoring error: [22](Invalid argument); GPO-based access control failed, but GPO is not in enforcing mode.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0020): waitpid did not found a child with changed status.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0020): child [6688] failed with status [1].
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [gpo_cse_done] (0x0020): ad_gpo_parse_gpo_child_response failed: [22][Invalid argument]
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_cse_done] (0x0040): Unable to retrieve policy data: [22](Invalid argument}
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): GPO-based access control failed.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): Ignoring error: [22](Invalid argument); GPO-based access control failed, but GPO is not in enforcing mode.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0020): child [6700] failed with status [1].
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_get_som_attrs_done] (0x0040): no attrs found for SOM; try next SOM
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [gpo_cse_done] (0x0020): ad_gpo_parse_gpo_child_response failed: [22][Invalid argument]
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_cse_done] (0x0040): Unable to retrieve policy data: [22](Invalid argument}
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): GPO-based access control failed.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): Ignoring error: [22](Invalid argument); GPO-based access control failed, but GPO is not in enforcing mode.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0020): child [6743] failed with status [1].
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_get_som_attrs_done] (0x0040): no attrs found for SOM; try next SOM
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [gpo_cse_done] (0x0020): ad_gpo_parse_gpo_child_response failed: [22][Invalid argument]
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_cse_done] (0x0040): Unable to retrieve policy data: [22](Invalid argument}
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): GPO-based access control failed.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_gpo_access_done] (0x0040): Ignoring error: [22](Invalid argument); GPO-based access control failed, but GPO is not in enforcing mode.
(Tue Sep 17 15:06:02 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0020): child [6763] failed with status [1].
(Tue Sep 17 15:16:18 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_ad_tokengroups_initgr_mapping_done] (0x0080): Domain not found for SID S-1-5-21-374409226-1497903906-623647154-2705
(Tue Sep 17 15:16:18 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_ad_tokengroups_initgr_mapping_done] (0x0080): Domain not found for SID S-1-5-21-374409226-1497903906-623647154-2663
(Tue Sep 17 15:16:18 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_ad_tokengroups_initgr_mapping_done] (0x0080): Domain not found for SID S-1-5-21-374409226-1497903906-623647154-1560
(Tue Sep 17 15:18:45 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_id_conn_data_expire_handler] (0x0080): connection is about to expire, releasing it
(Tue Sep 17 15:20:45 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_id_conn_data_expire_handler] (0x0080): connection is about to expire, releasing it
(Tue Sep 17 15:32:28 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_get_server_opts_from_rootdse] (0x0080): Received invalid value for AD compatibility level. Using the lowest-common compatibility level
(Tue Sep 17 15:47:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_id_conn_data_expire_handler] (0x0080): connection is about to expire, releasing it
(Tue Sep 17 15:48:28 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_get_server_opts_from_rootdse] (0x0080): Received invalid value for AD compatibility level. Using the lowest-common compatibility level
(Tue Sep 17 16:00:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_get_server_opts_from_rootdse] (0x0080): Received invalid value for AD compatibility level. Using the lowest-common compatibility level
(Tue Sep 17 16:00:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [postfix] in cache
(Tue Sep 17 16:00:01 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sysdb_get_real_name] (0x0040): Cannot find user [postfix] in cache
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_id_conn_data_expire_handler] (0x0080): connection is about to expire, releasing it
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:30 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_get_server_opts_from_rootdse] (0x0080): Received invalid value for AD compatibility level. Using the lowest-common compatibility level
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:33 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:33 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:33 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_process_init] (0x0080): No SUDO module provided for [XXXXXXXX] !!
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_process_init] (0x0020): No selinux module provided for [XXXXXXXX] !!
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_process_init] (0x0020): No host info module provided for [XXXXXXXX] !!
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_get_server_opts_from_rootdse] (0x0080): Received invalid value for AD compatibility level. Using the lowest-common compatibility level
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_run_online_cb] (0x0080): Going online. Running callbacks.
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_ptask_enable] (0x0080): Task [AD machine account password renewal]: already enabled
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_done] (0x0040): querying hosts database failed [5]: Input/output error
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [nsupdate_get_addrs_done] (0x0040): Could not resolve address for this machine, error [5]: Input/output error, resolver returned: [11]: Could not contact DNS servers
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [nsupdate_get_addrs_done] (0x0040): nsupdate_get_addrs_done failed: [5]: [Input/output error]
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_dyndns_dns_addrs_done] (0x0040): Could not receive list of current addresses [5]: Input/output error
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_dyndns_sdap_update_done] (0x0040): Dynamic DNS update failed [5]: Input/output error
(Tue Sep 17 16:03:34 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [ad_dyndns_nsupdate_done] (0x0040): Updating DNS entry failed [5]: Input/output error
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x0080): Connection is not open for dispatching.
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_process_init] (0x0080): No SUDO module provided for [XXXXXXXX] !!
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_process_init] (0x0020): No selinux module provided for [XXXXXXXX] !!
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_process_init] (0x0020): No host info module provided for [XXXXXXXX] !!
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [sdap_get_server_opts_from_rootdse] (0x0080): Received invalid value for AD compatibility level. Using the lowest-common compatibility level
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:22 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_run_online_cb] (0x0080): Going online. Running callbacks.
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:23 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [be_ptask_enable] (0x0080): Task [AD machine account password renewal]: already enabled
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:23 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_done] (0x0040): querying hosts database failed [5]: Input/output error
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:23 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [nsupdate_get_addrs_done] (0x0040): Could not resolve address for this machine, error [5]: Input/output error, resolver returned: [11]: Could not contact DNS servers
(Tue Sep 17 16:06:23 2019) [sssd[be[XXXXXXXX]]] [nsupdate_get_addrs_done] (0x0040): nsupdate_get_addrs_done failed: [5
```

Comment: `Could not open authorized keys '/home/SAGEX3/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory` and comparing to the other path `/home/XXXXXXXXXX.FR/sagex3/.ssh/authorized_keys` makes it look a missing home directory is the culprit, and not sssd. How do you mount home directories on both servers? Is the mechanism different? An other possible reason why `authorized_keys` cannot be found?

Comment: Hi, when the issue appears SSHD tries to find the key in the local's home and not on active directory user home . The user sageX3 is on both side AD and local. The connection is ok 99% of the time

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. You have both a local home and an "AD user home" for every user, is this correct? Does the AD home get automounted? How do you guarantee that the automounting is complete when ssh looks for for `authorized_keys`?